# working with window 7 files

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 yesterday with a dual boot with windows 7. I did a full Ubuntu install (not wubi).
 I have just noticed that I can mount my files from windows 7 when I am booted to Ubuntu 12.04.
 I was wondering if I can work with my user windows 7 files when I am in Ubuntu I know how picky windows is and I dont want to mess anything up by accessing the window files when I am not booted to window.

thank you

Comment: Would you please be more specific as to the error. How, **precisely**, do you try to mount your Windows 7 files from Ubuntu; and what, **specifically**, happens? (It works effortlessly on my machine.)

Answer (score 0):

There's **no harm** in working with your various **data files** (e.g. documents, music, pictures, videos) in your **Windows** partition(s) when you're in **Ubuntu** as long as you keep away from Windows system files, applications files, etc.
You should only consider which **applications** you should use for which **file formats** carefully in view of different levels of **compatibility**.